# Ruby Selenium Webdriver - configuring Sauce Labs Pass/Fail

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, saucelabs

Sauce Labs has a specific `:passed` option that can be used to report the pass/fail status of a test - (https://saucelabs.com/docs/additional-config).

I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to accomplish this in Ruby.

I've tried creating a global variable (`$status`) in my **class** that is used as a placeholder for the value of `:passed` for the Sauce Labs test. Then during **teardown** updating the placeholder to the appropriate value.

In this example the test will always return as `Fail`

in my **class**

```
$status = false
```

in my **setup**

```
caps[:passed] = $status
```

in my **teardown**

```
def success
  $status = true
end

def error
  $status = false
end
```

I'm assuming that `caps[:passed] = $status` is *set* during **setup** and can't be changed.

I have no idea how to update the `:passed` status after the job is complete.

Comment: I've also tried simply adding `caps[:passed] = true` in my **teardown** but it just gets ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by using the `sauce_whisk` gem (https://github.com/saucelabs/sauce_whisk)

*"SauceWhisk provides an "ActiveRecord" style client for the Sauce Labs RESTful API. If you're not using the Sauce Gem and you want a nice way to interact with our API, give this a try."*

During `driver` setup retrieve the *SauceLabs Job ID* - something like `@job_id = @driver.instance_variable_get("@bridge").instance_variable_get("@session_id")`

Then during teardown I can use `SauceWhisk::Jobs.pass_job @job_id` or `SauceWhisk::Jobs.fail_job @job_id` to set the status of the job.

Answer (score 0):

An example straight from Sauce Labs [found here](http://saucelabs.com/docs/ondemand/getting-started/env/ruby/se2/mac).

```
require 'rubygems'
require "test/unit"
require 'selenium-webdriver'

class ExampleTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def setup
        caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox
        caps.version = "5"
        caps.platform = :XP
        caps[:name] = "Testing Selenium 2 with Ruby on Sauce"

        @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(
          :remote,
          :url => "http://username-string:access-key-string@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub",
          :desired_capabilities => caps)
    end

    def test_sauce
        @driver.navigate.to "http://saucelabs.com/test/guinea-pig"
        assert @driver.title.include?("I am a page title - Sauce Labs")
    end

    def teardown
        @driver.quit
    end
end
```

Comment: Aww sorry @sircapsalot I should be clearer. There's a specific `:passed` option in Sauce Labs, but I can't find a clear example of how to use it (in Ruby).

Thanks for the help though.